# Printing 2D char array in Java with For loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, printing

In class I was told that printing out a 2D char array is done by using two for loops. Can someone please explain to me how this works? Thank you.

My code is below (it should print a tic tac toe board)

Here's a photo of my output: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lS1c.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TicTacToe{

   public static void main(String [] args){



            char[][] gameBoard = {{' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
                                        {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'},
                                        {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
                                        {'-', '+', '-', '+', '-'},
                                        {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}};


         for(char [] row: gameBoard){
          for(char c: row){
            System.out.print(c);
          }
            System.out.println();
          }

     }

 }
```

Comment: Is there a problem? Or are you asking us to explain your code to you?

Comment: @shmosel The latter, unfortuantely.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: Please explain the code!

Answer (score 0):

The reason two loops are used in your code is because you need to print **EACH** character in **EACH** row.

The outer loop gets you each row and the inner loop gets you each character **WITHIN** that row. So in the first iteration of the outer loop you get the top row. Now that you're accesing it, you can go ahead and loop through each of the characters it holds with the inner loop and print them.

Once all characters in that row have been printed, the inner loop ends and the next row is accessed and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The two for loops are used to print a row character by character before moving on to the next row. A 2D array is essentially an array of arrays, or in this case, an array of rows. The outer loop loops through every row on the board, and for each of those rows, the inner loop iterates through the characters in it. I added some comments in hopes of clarifying this.

```
 for(char [] row: gameBoard){   //loops through each row in the gameboard 
    for(char c: row){           //loops through each character in the current row
      System.out.print(c);      //prints out the current character in the current row
    }
    System.out.println();       //creates a new line after all characters in a row have been printed
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a ton!  So if you use the work "row", this will tell the compiler that you want to loop through each row of the gameBoard array?

Comment: No, the identifier "row" is just a variable name for the counter for the outer loop. This is an enhanced for loop, in which the program is looping through the rows and assigns the current one to the variable "row". The actual name doesn't matter. The same goes for the "char c: row". It is looping through the current row (saved as "row" from the outer loop) and assigns each character to the variable "c", which is then printed out.